# WordPress: Getting title tag in PHP variable

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, yoast

I am using Yoast SEO for SEO on the website. In my header file I have added

`<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>`

I have also added `<?php wp_head(); ?>` in header.
Also enabled **Force rewrite titles** but still the title tag which I have added in page while editing it, in SEO Snippet is not displaying on webpage.

I have not added support for `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` - *Adding it and removing title tag from head also won't make any difference*

So my question here is how I can grab the title tag **Added in snippet** and at list echo it out in page. On API for Yoast they have listed some hooks and filters but their are no examples.

Can get it by `wpseo_title`?

Comment: For the future, this may have been more on topic at the Wordpress Stack Exchange https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to add `add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );` in functions.php and remove any `<title></title>` tags from header.php